# Posting a textarea form with cURL

Tags: php, forms, curl, textarea, submit

How would I go about posting a textarea form?

```
<form method="post" action="/user/test/shoutbox/add" id="shoutPost" class="clearit">
<input name="formtoken" type="hidden" value="852f8fde54190fa5f9aa47172d492f829c1b"/>
<input type="hidden" name="backto" value="/user/test/shoutbox" />
<textarea id="shoutmsg" name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="confirmButton" value="Post" id="sbPost"  />
```

**This should work right?**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postfields .= "&message=".$msg;
$postfields .= "&submit=sbPost";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

but it's not posting for some reason...

Comment: are all other fields posting except for the textarea?

Comment: No. The token posts itself with page load.

Comment: Are you trying to POST data to the page that has that form or getting the results from the compiled form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,"URLHERE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"URLHERE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    $formtoken = explode('name="formtoken" type="hidden" value="',$page);
    $formtoken = explode('"/> ',$formtoken[1]);
    $formtoken = $formtoken[0];

    $backto = explode('type="hidden" name="backto" value="',$page);
    $backto = explode('" />',$backto[1]);
    $backto = $backto[0];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookiejar-$randnum");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"URLHERE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $postfields = "formtoken=".$formtoken;
    $postfields .= "&backto=".$backto;
    $postfields .= "&message=".$msg;
    $postfields .= "&submit=Post";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the curl_exec?

```
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: No, I have all of that. I just posted the postfields to see if I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Where is $msg coming from? your text area has name="message", try changing $msg to $_POST['message']

Comment: $msg is just "TEST". It's a variable at the top.